# почему постфиксный оператор не выполняется раньше всего?

Tags: c#

```
int a = 1;
a = ++a * a++;
int b = 1;
b = b++ * ++b;
```

Почему a = 4, b = 3?
Приоритет у постфиксного оператора же больше, значит он выполнится до префиксного и умножения. Разве не так?

Comment: Понимаю, что какие-то учебные примеры и всё такое, но хочу сказать, что в реальной жизни адекватные люди так не пишут. А кто пишет - надо руки выдёргивать))

Comment: Спасибо, писать так никогда не буду, но хотелось бы понять смысл.

Comment: рассмотри умножение и эти операторы, как функции, получишь что-то вроде: `a = mul(inc_pre(a), inc_post(a))`, самой функции `mul` не важно в каком порядке вычисляются переданные ей аргументы, и, в принципе, компилятор может сам решить что выполнится сначала.

Comment: А почему голоса за закрытие? Хороший вопрос, хоть и часто встречающийся.

Comment: @Grundy: В C# это не так, порядок вычисления строго определён. Другиое дело, что компилятор может его нарушить, если докажет, что результат от этого не поменяется.

Comment: @VladD, и это хорошо :) Кстати, а что с аргументами функций, они тоже в строгом порядке вычисляются?

Comment: @Grundy: Да, конечно. Вызов функции — это такой же узел, просто с большим числом дочерних узлов.

Answer (score 3):

Приоритет никак не связан с порядком операций. Приоритеты лишь позволяют иногда (если они подобраны хорошо, то часто) писать без скобок.

В C# правило следующее: выражения вычисляются строго (с точностью до [as-if-правила](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As-if_rule)) слева направо. Точнее, строится дерево выражения, и обход его производится в [обратном порядке](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4): левое поддерево, затем правое поддерево, затем сам узел.

Выражение `a = ++a * a++` даёт такое дерево:

```
        assign
        /    \
      a(1)    *
            /   \
  preincrement  postincrement
          /       \
        a(2)      a(3)
```

Вычисление:

1. Вычисляем корневой узел assign, для этого:
2. Вычисляем адрес `a` (1).
3. Начинаем вычислять правый аргумент присваивания, для этого:
4. Начинаем вычислять преинкремент, для этого:
5. Вычисляем адрес `a` (2)
6. Выполняем преинкремент (`a` становится равным 2, значение узла 2).
7. Начинаем вычислять постинкремент, для этого:
8. Берём снова адрес `a` (3)
9. Выполняем постинкремент (`a` становится равным 3, значение узла 2).
10. Умножение даёт 4.
11. Выполняем присваивание, `a` становится равным 4.

Выражение `b = b++ * ++b` даёт такое дерево:

```
        assign
        /    \
      b(1)    *
            /   \
 postincrement  preincrement
          /       \
        b(2)      b(3)
```

Вычисление:

1. Вычисляем корневой узел assign, для этого:
2. Вычисляем адрес `b` (1).
3. Начинаем вычислять правый аргумент присваивания, для этого:
4. Начинаем вычислять постинкремент, для этого:
5. Вычисляем адрес `b` (2)
6. Выполняем постинкремент (`b` становится равным 2, значение узла 1).
7. Начинаем вычислять преинкремент, для этого:
8. Берём снова адрес `b` (3)
9. Выполняем преинкремент (`b` становится равным 3, значение узла 3).
10. Умножение даёт 3.
11. Выполняем присваивание, `b` становится равным 3.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Eric Lippert. *Precedence vs associativity vs order*.](https://ericlippert.com/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order/)

Ещё один забавный пример [тут](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWAChGA3AQygAJ2pWBPDgLwc8MAO4cAlngwBtKgF0A3C3aS8hGAkEcADMobc+MqRoTztJEic36KNAJwAKRh1ccAJACJrWoQG8fAF80LigefiEZDj9DXhkdeWDo2JkaRI55TwBKfSA=).

---

В отличие от C#, в некоторых других языках (например, C++) порядок вычисления может быть не определён, а выражения наподобие тех, которые вы привели, могут приводить и вовсе к [неопределённому поведению](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior#Examples_in_C_and_C++).

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @нольайкью: Пожалуйста! Обращайтесь :)

Comment: Очень подробный и качественный ответ! От себя добавлю что нагляднее всего можно смотреть реальные деревья в linqpad - закладка "Tree". Вот так например выглядит пример первого дерева из ответа: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwbfl.png

Comment: @AK: Или [вот тут](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzhtAExAGoAfASwDsMACbWgXloEYBuAWACgHmSSGAKnr82QA=): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIcPN.png). // Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Да вроде всё логично.

```
int a = 1;
a = ++a * a++;
```

Оператор `++a` увеличивает `a` и возвращает увеличенное значение.
А оператор `a++` наоборот - сначала возвращает значение, а потом увеличивает `a`.
Что мы имеем, т.е. что возвращает инкремент и чему после этого равно `a`:

```
a = ++a * a++;
    ^^^   ^^^
   2(a=2) 2(a=3)
```

После `a++` в `a` будет `3`, но это значение тут же затрётся после присваивания результата `a = 2 * 2`, поэтому в `a` будет 4.

```
int b = 1;
b = b++ * ++b;
    ^^^   ^^^
   1(b=2) 3(b=3)
```

Тут в `b` и так уже `3` после двух инкрементов, и после присваивания результата вычисления `b = 1 * 3` - тоже `3`.